# Is it posible to separate Javascript and CSS code from HTML code in a Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: html, c++, visual-studio-2010, atl

In my project I have several HTML-JavaScript-CSS code and I want to split them into different files.
The control I am using is derived from ATL CAxWindow.

> Environment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
>
> Programming Language: C++, JavaScript, HTML.

The problema arises when I try to separaste the scripting and style codes into separate files. The HTML document generated won't detect those files since they're not included in the resources of the Project, like the HTML document is.

Do you know how can I include those?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have to include both, .css and .js files in the Visual Studio environment by adding the resources to the project. This will allow to the system to include those on the generated solution and make the files accessible for your HTML code.

Once you have included the files on your solution, a number identifying the resource will appear on the resources header file. You have to include that resource identificator as the source for the javascript and css files. For instance:

```
In case my ID is -> 1
I have to write on my html ->  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./1">
```

Hope it helps!